# Retrieving JSON from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I am using D3js to parse some information and would like the JSON to be stored online rather than locally. I am pulling the JSON from firebase doing the following:

```
 var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child("main_bubble.json");
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url);
});
```

it returns the URL properly, but how do I convert it into JSON?

Comment: Did you try this?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes I tried that but I keep getting no Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelenI figured it out! Thank you! I had to change the cors.json file to allow my domain to query it.